# Dynamicly apply filter for one2many field in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I need to filter records shown in one2many tree when I click a button or change another field

I have tried tens of times with different techniques but it doesn't work

here is the last try to figure out the problem

first in the main model

```
current_exercise = 'exercise 1'   

generalFitnessDetails = One2many("spogaze.general_fitness_details", "generalFitnessDetails",                                     domain=[('exercise', '=', '%s' % current_exercise)])
```

the detailed model which represented with O2M field has 'exercise' field which I need to apply the filter depends on it

in the main model I added a function to change the 'current_exercise' value and applying the filter

```
@api.one
def next_exercise(self):
        self.current_exercise = 'exercise 2' 

        return {'domain': {'generalFitnessDetails': [('exercise', '=', self.current_exercise)]}}
```

but what happens is that the first filter applied which is stated in O2M field creation before I click the button, but after clicking the button the field "current_exercise" changes but filter doesn't apply

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't need button to accomplish this.

Create a related field in the one2many model, like -

```
'current_exercise' = field.Type(related="many2one_field.current_exercise",
                                string="your string")
```

Then write a domain based on that related field.

Comment: did you mean I have to create this field in detail model not the main model?, note that current_exercise field is just a flag in main model to filter one2many tree

Comment: Yes, in the detail model. If that is a flag you won't need that. Create related field of the main field (from main model), use detail models field (related one) to filter as you need.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, the idea is to apply the filter when the user clicks a button so I need code to apply the filter